# Select rows in mysql where difference between timestamp = 5 Minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with a column "timestamp".

Now I want to select the elements with a difference of 5 minutes from each other.

Simplified example:

```
id   |    timestamp
===================
1    |    00:00
2    |    00:01
3    |    00:03
4    |    00:05
5    |    00:07
6    |    00:09
7    |    00:15
```

should return the ids `1, 4, 7`

is this possible with a sql statement?

Comment: This is basic maths right?

Comment: what is the type of that column?

Comment: Yes basic math, I expect the real question is how to do this in SQL, and not the problem of the mathematics. Remeber also the complication that the timestamp may or may not be a unix time value (ie seconds since 1st Jan 1970). Also using modulus 5 (as in Niels solution) will work, but the op may also need to take into account a specified 'time zero' instant for thier situation, adds complication.

Comment: It isn't basic maths which will answer this question. It is more of an SQL issue than basic maths. The math part they have already solved

Comment: the column is of type "timestamp". A modulo operation is not sufficient. I really have to check the timestamp column

Comment: it should return all entries with a difference of 5 minutes from the first entry. The first entry may not start with 00:00.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, which should work no matter what's the first timestamp.

```
SELECT id, ts FROM (
SELECT 
IF(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) = @prev OR UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) % 300 = @prev % 300, @mybool:=1, @mybool:=0) AS mybool,
IF(@mybool = 1, @prev:=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts), @prev:=@prev),
t.*
FROM Table2 t,
(SELECT @prev:=(SELECT MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts)) FROM Table2 sqt), @mybool:=1) vars
ORDER BY id
) sq 
WHERE mybool = 1;
```

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7fe62/9/1).

If the first timestamp is '00:00' you can simply do

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) % 300 = 0
ORDER BY id;
```

but you have to work with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to make it work. A timestamp is stored in database as a 32-bit integer, still you have to tell MySQL that you want to work with the integer representation.

Comment: P.S.: I must admit, I'm not sure, if `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) % 300 = @prev % 300` is bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from table where timestamp % 5 = 0
```

Precise syntax depends a bit on the datatype of the `timestamp` column but in general you should be able to do it with the modulo operator.

Comment: @Strawberry yes and no - it answers the question, if the set can be more complex (for example having to check the first row for the offset) OP would have to add it to his question. Also it's easily extendable from this base.

Comment: I still think it fails to fulfil the brief - but I have to concede that the brief is too poorly defined to know one way or the other.

Comment: What about times 00:01 and 00:06? (since OP mentioned their example is just simplified data)

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ we cannot answer cases like that without more information from the OP. If this answers the simplified example but not the more complex real question the question was too simplified, simple as that  :)

Comment: No one is suggesting a modulo on the `id`, that would be silly. The modulo on the timestamp still works (albeit you'd have to `% 300` since a `timestamp` is in seconds), but you'd have to find some sort of initial offset.